# mongoose schema unique by 2 fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to set 2 fields to being unique to each other and not have duplicates.

The code is this :

```
const Connection = mongoose.model("Connection", new mongoose.Schema({
    from_friend: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Friend'
    },
    to_friend: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Friend'
    }
}))
exports.Connection = Connection;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a unique index that includes both fields

```
const ConnectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    from_friend: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Friend'
    },
    to_friend: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Friend'
    }
});

ConnectionSchema.index({ from_friend: 1, to_friend: 1 }, { unique: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Connection', ConnectionSchema);
```

Comment: does not work, i can still create duplicate objects. i also assume you meant new mongoose.Schema on the first line.

Comment: @alexlug try now

Comment: your answer was good but incomplete. because i had to reset the DB. I approved it nontheless. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### [The unique Option is Not a Validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator)

> A common gotcha for beginners is that the unique option for schemas is not a validator. It's a convenient helper for building MongoDB unique indexes. See the FAQ for more information.

From the [FAQ](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#unique-doesnt-work):

> Q. I declared a schema property as unique but I can still save duplicates. What gives?
>
> A. Mongoose doesn't handle unique on its own: `{ name: { type: String, unique: true } }` is just a shorthand for creating a MongoDB unique index on name. For example, if MongoDB doesn't already have a unique index on name, the below code will not error despite the fact that unique is true.
>
> `var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
>     name: { type: String, unique: true }
>   });
>   var Model = db.model('Test', schema);
>   Model.create([{ name: 'Val' }, { name: 'Val' }], function(err) {
>     console.log(err); // No error, unless index was already built
>   });`
>
> However, if you wait for the index to build using the `Model.on('index')` event, attempts to save duplicates will correctly error.

You will need to write your own [custom validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators).

> If the built-in validators aren't enough, you can define custom validators to suit your needs.
>
> Custom validation is declared by passing a validation function. You can find detailed instructions on how to do this in the SchemaType#validate() API docs.

Comment: no idea what you wrote there honestly ... i'm kind of new to Express ..

Comment: Check the links. I updated the answer with quotes from them. Basically, `unique` is not a validator. It's a helper for MongoDB indexes. What you are after is custom validation logic. Relying upon `unqiue` is risky because the indexes may not be setup before you have data coming in as they are not meant for validation.